# the meaning of * (zero time or many times) in the python regular expression

Tags: python, regex

Why  `print(re.search("c*","bccc").group())`  get nothing ? I think it will get `ccc` too, `*` is zero time or many times ,`c*` can match `ccc`,why can't get ccc in the expression`re.search("c*","bccc")`?

```
>>> print(re.search("c*","ccc").group())  
ccc  
>>> print(re.search("c*","bccc").group())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regular expressions scan from the start, and `re.search()` returns the first legal match. Because you asked for zero or more `c` characters, the empty string is the first legal match.

Either use `re.findall()` to find *all* non-overlapping legal matches:

```
>>> re.findall("c*","bccc")
['', 'ccc', '']
```

or add an anchor:

```
>>> re.search("c*$","bccc").group()
'ccc'
```

or use `+` to match 1 or more characters:

```
>>> re.search("c+","bccc").group()
'ccc'
```

Comment: why `re.findall("","bccc")` get five blank as the result?
`['', '', '', '', '']`  ?

Comment: @it_is_a_literature: there is a zero-width string after each of the characters.

Comment: `c*` stand for zero or more c characters,when it stand for zero c character,re.findall("c*","bccc")=re.findall("","bccc")=['', '', '', '', ''];when  `c*` stand for more c characters,re.findall("c*","bccc")='ccc', so the total result will be ['', '', '', '', '','ccc'],in fact ,it's not ,why?

Comment: @it_is_a_literature: Those other matches *overlap*, `findall()` only finds non-overlapping matches.

Comment: why re.findall("c*","bccc")=['', 'ccc', ''],why not re.findall("c*","bccc")=['', 'ccc'],what is the meaning of last '' in the result?why it is not the overlapping match as the first '' in the same result?

Comment: There is still a matching zero-width string at the end, it doesn't overlap with the `'ccc'` match.

Comment: `c*`=zero or ccc here ,so `''|ccc` can stand for `c*` here, why ` re.findall("''|ccc","bccc")` get `
['ccc'] ` ,not ['', 'ccc', ''] ?

Comment: @it_is_a_literature: You are trying to match `''`, not an empty string there. `re.findall("|c*","bccc")` would find 5 empty strings, `re.findall("c*|","bccc")` finds `['', 'ccc', '']`.

Comment: i totally understand with analysing the operating process,think martijn.